# Ngxs - State is undefined

Tags: angular, state, ngxs

just started playing around ngxs and hit a road block.
I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but I'm getting 'state is undefined' error.

**Action:**

```
const prefix = "[Tutorial]";

export class AddTutorial {
  static readonly type = `${prefix} Add Tutorial`;

  constructor(public payload: string) { }
}
```

**State:**

```
export class TutorialStateModel {
  tutorial: any[]
}

@State<TutorialStateModel>({
  name: 'tutorial',
  defaults: {
    tutorial: [],
  }
})
export class TutorialState {

  @Action(AddTutorial)
  addTutorial({ getState, patchState }: StateContext<TutorialStateModel>, { payload }: AddTutorial) {
    const state = getState();
    patchState({
      tutorial: [...state.tutorial, payload]
    });
  }

}
```

error points to: `const state = getState();`

**Component:**

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.store.dispatch(new AddTutorial('Redux'));
  }
```

Comment: I can't see anything obvious, I copied your code to a test app, and it is working fine - I can see the the tutorial list updating.
I'm using NGXS 3.0.1. Is there any more info you can post here?

Comment: I pasted your snippets into an existing ngxs app. It ran without issue so problem is something else.

Comment: I'm getting undefined values on getState().

Comment: chill...i'm sure you will figure it out. here's the stackblitz demo with your code running - https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngxs-so-tutorial-state i would cross check your dependencies, import statements and environment (i.e. node, typescript)

Answer (score 1):

It was my cache. I cleared it and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with state being `undefined` in @Selector.

In my case the **feature state module was not imported in the component's module** which used that selector